# RangetoHTML keeping TempWB open

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Ron de Bruin's RangetoHTML without modification to copy a range to an html email body. On my pc in Excel 2010, it works as intended. On a colleague's pc running Excel 2016, it appears to take the range, create the temp workbook and stop. The temp workbook includes the correct range, but it never makes it to the email body, nor does the code close out and delete the temp workbook. It still correctly populates the to/cc and subject but the .HTMLbody is blank. Any ideas?

Code below:

```
...
On Error Resume Next

    Dim objOutlook as Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim objEmail as Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objEmail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Attachments.Add (attachmentPath)
        .Subject = strSubject
        .HTMLbody = RangetoHTML(rng) & signature
        .Display
    End With
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
'Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
'Working in Office 2000-2016

Dim fso as Object
Dim ts as Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim  TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
rng.copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
    SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
    Filename:=TempFile, _
    Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name
    Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
    HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1,-2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
"align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in the function
Kill TempFile

Set ts= Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: will add, have to retype from remote desktop

Comment: No need for the function itself if you did not modify it, but instead the calling function, which you partially included. At first glance, I would remove `On Error Resume Next` as that is never a good idea, as you will get unexpected results, and that seems to be what is happening - inconsistent, unexpected results. So when you remove that, are you getting an error? If so, what error? On which line?

Comment: The "On Error Resume Next" was in Ron's code so I left it but I can remove. No errors because it executes as intended on my version. 2016 executes without errors either, just doesn't copy the range to the email body.